# measurable functions commute with conditional expectation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $W_t = W (t)$ be a (one-dimensional) Wiener process, and fix an admissible filtration $\mathbb{F}.$
An adapted process $V_t$ is called elementary if it has the form
$$V_t = \sum_{j = 0}^{k} \xi_j \chi_{(tj ,tj+1]}(t)$$
where $0 = t_0 < t_1 <···< t_k = 1,$ and for each index j the random variable $\xi_j$ is measurable relative to $\mathcal{F}_{t_j}.$
Define the Ito Integral of a simple process as follows:
$$I_{t}(V) = \int_{0}^{t}V_{s}dW_{s} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}\xi_j(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})$$
In some proofs of the properties of the Ito Integral, I see the following type of argument: (For simplicity, I will use a process with only one jump.)
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(I_{t}(V)\right)&= \mathbb{E}(\xi_j(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}}))\\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\xi_j(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})| \mathcal{F}_{t_{i+1}}\right)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\xi_{j}\left[\mathbb{E}\left((W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})| \mathcal{F}_{t_{i+1}}\right)\right]
\end{align*}
I have been staring at this for a bit, but I am unsure where this string of equalities comes from. I am guessing that the second inequality comes from the Tower Property for conditional expectations? Also where the heck does the third equality come from? If we write this out we've
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega}I_{t}(V)d\mu &= \int_{\Omega}\xi_j(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})d\mu\\
 &= \int_{\Omega}\int_{\mathcal{F}_{t_{i+1}}}\xi_j(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})d\mu d\mu \\
&=\int_{\Omega}\xi_{j}\int_{\mathcal{F}_{t_{i+1}}}(W_{t_{j+1}} - W_{t_{j}})d\mu d\mu
\end{align*}
where $(\Omega,\mu)$ is the background measure space. I still don't see why we can pull out the measurable function like that. Are my definitions wrong? Please help.

Comment: $\mathcal F_{t_{j+1}}\supset \mathcal F_{t_j}$ so if $\xi_j$ is measurable with $\mathcal F_{t_j}$ it is measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_{t_{j+1}}$ and hence we can pull it out as a known factor - no tower property involved.

Comment: What do you mean by integral over a sigma algebra? I think you should take a set in the sigma algebra and integrate over it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I guess I don't really know how to define conditional expectation as an integral. Is the correct definition

Comment: @Index Conditional expectation is a random variable in general, not a number. It is not an integral.

Comment: @Math1000 I'm not sure what you mean by a "known factor". Like, if it is measurable with respect to a sub sigma algebra, we can think of it as a constant?

Comment: If $X$ is $\mathcal H$-measurable, then $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathcal H]=X$. That is all.